# Knife tool isn't working, at all

Tags: knife-tool

I'm trying to use the knife tool. My scene has a small scale, set up in millimetres. I've set the "Auto merge" to 0.01mm and lowered the view clipping to 0.01mm. When I select the knife tool in edit mode I can't click anything. The bisect tool works, the loopcut tool works, but the knife tool doesn't do anything. This applies to every object in the scene, if I make a new cube and try to use the knife tool nothing happens. I'm using Blender 2.90.0

I've seen others saying that knife tool doesn't work in their scene but since you need 50 rep to comment I can't ask them if they are working on a small scale (which is probably the cause of my problem).

Comment: Hi :) Would you please [add an image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/199406/edit) or better yet, [a gif](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) showing the problem you are having? Have you tried [loading factory settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/configuration/defaults.html#loading-factory-settings)? Linking to relevant Q's you might have found here is useful also, to help find a solution. :)

Comment: Image or gif won’t give any extra information, nothing happens when I click using the knife tool, no matter where or what I click, no matter what I have selected. Default settings work, the problem appears to have something to do with setting blender to mm scale and doing small models.